# Find nearest smaller number in array

Tags: swift

I would like to be able to find the nearest smaller value in an array of numbers. For instance, if I have:

```
[1, 4, 6, 9, 14, 39]
```

And I'm looking for the nearest value smaller than:

```
8
```

The function would return:

```
6
```

Additionally, if I pass a number greater than the maximum value in the array, it should return the maximum. If I pass a number smaller than the minimum, it should return nil.

I tried doing this using the `first` function on arrays, however this on its own doesn't produce the result I'm looking for as I would need something like this:

```
numbers.first(where: { $0 <= target && $1 < target })
```

but unfortunately, this isn't valid. Any suggestions? I know this could be done fairly trivially with a while loop, however I was hoping there would be a cleaner, functional way.

Comment: `let result = numbers.last { $0 < target }`.

Comment: A *binary search* would be the most efficient method for large (sorted) arrays.

Comment: What result do you expect if the target is `14`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the array is sorted , You need

```
if let value = numbers.last(where: { $0 <= target }) {
  print(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic solution using binary search. The array must be sorted

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Element : Comparable {
    func lowerElement(of value: Element) -> Element? {
        var slice : SubSequence = self[...]

        while !slice.isEmpty {
            let middle = slice.index(slice.startIndex, offsetBy: slice.count / 2)
            if value < slice[middle] {
                slice = slice[..<middle]
            } else {
                slice = slice[index(after: middle)...]
            }
        }
        return slice.startIndex == self.startIndex ? nil : self[self.index(before: slice.startIndex)]
    }
}

let array = [1, 4, 6, 9, 14, 39]
let result = array.lowerElement(of: 8)
print(result)
```